# Pagination for previous page/next page (with more than one post/page)

Tags: pagination

I have a template that displays 3 blog posts per page. I want to use Wordpress pagination for previous/next, but the pagination won't display on my page.

Here's the code I have now for `template-blog.php` (UPDATE: I moved this to `home.php` as well):

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
else { $paged = 1; }

$args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'paged' => $paged);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    // (I display the post here)
}

<div class='pagination'>
    <?php previous_posts_link('%link', '<span>Previous</span>', TRUE); ?>
    <?php next_posts_link('%link', '<span>Next</span>', TRUE); ?>
</div>
```

This code displays posts #1 through #3 but no next/previous link. There are still two more posts (#4 and #5) which should be on the next page of posts, so there should be a "Previous" link. And if I manually change the URL to `/blog/2`, sure enough, there are posts #2 and #1.

(I also tried `previous_post_link` and `next_post_link`, for per-post navigation, and they display a link that goes to just the previous post. Which is no good.)

**UPDATE 1:** I noticed that `$the_query->max_num_pages == 2`, which is correct (I've loaded 5 test posts into the system). So at least Wordpress knows there's another page.

**UPDATE 2:** I changed my code to use `query_posts()`... still no luck, `previous_posts_link` and `next_posts_link` displays nothing.

**UPDATE 3:** I've moved this code into `home.php`, and changed Settings > Reading to make this page the main "posts" page. Now I can confirm that Wordpress is using `home.php` as the template file to display the blog page, but it still won't display any pagination.

---

Comment: `next_posts_link` acts on the main (global) `$wp_query` object, and you have a custom query displaying posts... it won't work

Comment: Hmm... I've tried changing it to `$wp_query->new WP_Query ($args)` and still no luck. What else do you recommend? I have also changed to `query_posts()` which didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

Reference: [posts_nav_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/posts_nav_link#Examples)

```
<div class="navigation">
<div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Entries') ?></div>
<div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('Next Entries &raquo;','') ?></div>
</div>
```

Don't use `next_post_link` or `previous_post_link` they are used for single post pagination.

Comment: Tried that, and they don't display any nav on the page at all.

Comment: can you try to echo $paged and tell us what it echos

Comment: Sure. `$paged == 1` both before and after The Loop.

Comment: My mistake: you're right. I was passing too many parameters to `previous_posts_link()` and it was getting confused. (See in my original question, where I pass 3 parameters? Turns out it only accepts one. Dur.) Thanks.